# The provider provider.terraform does not support resource type "terraform_remote_state

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have very simple Terraform setup for beginner -

main.tf -

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = var.access_key
  secret_key = var.secret_key
  region     = var.region
  version    = "~> 2.8"
}

resource "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket = var.vpc_bucket
    region = var.region
    key    = var.vpc_bucket_key
  }
}
```

And the variables.tf -

```
variable "access_key" {
  default = ""
}
variable "secret_key" {
  default = ""
}

variable "vpc_bucket" {
  default = "ops-bucket-0708"
}

variable "region" {
  default = "ap-south-1"
}

variable "vpc_bucket_key" {
  default = "aws/ap-south-1/VPCs/terraform.tfstate"
}
```

When I run `terraform plan` it gives me the error below -

```
Error: Invalid resource type

  on main.tf line 8, in resource "terraform_remote_state" "vpc":
   8: resource "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {

The provider provider.terraform does not support resource type
"terraform_remote_state".
```

What am I doing here ?

Comment: I had a similar problem to your question, but my solution was running `terraform init -upgrade`. Commenting here in case anyone else stumbles on your question for the same reason I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[terraform_remote_state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) is a `data`, not a `resource`.

Thus you can try the following:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket = var.vpc_bucket
    region = var.region
    key    = var.vpc_bucket_key
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar issue. I am using data only. the error is - The provider hashicorp/aws does not support data source
│ "terraform_remote_state". I also undertsand that - data "terraform_remote_state" is available as a terraform provider and not aws. However this should be available as default, should not need any provider.